# My API Call Isn't Returning Anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, getjson

I'm checking to see if a Twitch.com user has ever existed. When I check the API call it is returning a value in the browser, but not in the console.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/comster404", function(data2){
  // console.log(data2.status);
  console.log(data2);
});
```

This is the data it should get
       {
"error": "Unprocessable Entity",
"status": 422,
"message": "Channel 'comster404' is not available on Twitch"
}

Comment: Probably: [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). They appear to support JSONP, because if I add `?callback=foo`, I get a proper JSONP response. Look at the [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/) docs for JSONP info.

Comment: [Here's a JSONP demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rkyza45u/) that shows it working.

Comment: Adding ?callback=? to the URL will make it a JSONP is that correct?

Comment: Yes. jQuery will assign a function name to be called in place of the `?`. If you plug that URL into your browser's address bar, but substitute your own function name for the last `?`, you'll see that the request will come back as a script that calls that function and passes it the data.

Comment: ...like this: [https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/comster404?callback=foo](https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/comster404?callback=foo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've passed a `success` callback but no `error` callback. Since an error occurred when fetching that URL, the `success` callback would not be called.

You can set the callbacks for `success` and `error` with `done()` and `fail()` respectively:

```js
var log = document.getElementById("log");

$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/comster404")
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    log.innertHTML += "success!";
  })
  .fail(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    log.innerHTML += error.responseText;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Nice, so this will do it as a JSON and not a JSONP then?

Comment: Yes, it will be treated as JSON.

Comment: @user2872518: It will work in [browsers that support CORS](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors). If you need to support older browsers, you'll need JSONP.